# Python Tuple within a Tuple

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples, quote

I have a python question.

I generated this list

```
14:00,18.7,383.5,266405,5480,212500,183750,52380,6804,57150,17431,65567
14:01,18.7,383.5,226430,6600,210850,206700,51870,11868,69850,18486,59222
```

Now I want to make it into

```
('14:00', 18.7, 383.5,
(266405, 5480, 212500, 183750, 52380, 6804, 57150, 17431, 65567)),

('14:01', 18.7, 383.5,
(226430, 6600, 210850, 206700, 51870, 11868, 69850, 18486, 59222)),
```

I have learned how to convert a list into a tuple,
by doing tuple(list)

But I have no idea how to create a tuple and quote within a tuple..

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use slicing to get sub-sequence, and convert it to `tuple` using [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple).

```
>>> lst = ['14:00',18.7,383.5,266405,5480,212500,183750,52380,6804,57150,17431,65567]
>>> tuple(lst[:3]) + (tuple(lst[3:]),)
('14:00', 18.7, 383.5, (266405, 5480, 212500, 183750, 52380, 6804, 57150, 17431, 65567))
```